# How to connect to MySQL on a Solaris Sun System

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to MySQL Database that is hosted on a Windows Server 2008. But I want to connect to it while using a Solaris Sun System.

What client can I use for connection for Solaris Sun system?

Thanks

Comment: Euhm, at risk of being Captain Obvious - the MySQL client for solaris? See, e.g. http://opencsw.org

Comment: Unless you want to connect programmatically, then specifying the language you wanna do it in would help..

Comment: I want to connect using some program like MySQL Workbench. But I need a version for Solaris. I don't want to connect using a programming language but I need to be able to connect using a client. @opencsw.org you mentioned MySQL client for solaris. Where can I find that?  Thanks

Comment: MySQL Workbench is a GUI tool. Are you sure that is what you want on Solaris?  On Solaris 11 you can do `pkg install database/mysql-5`. This will install both Server and Client binaries. Just ignore the Server side binaries and then use the `mysql` command line client.